# Compile docker on armv7

Tags: docker, arm

It seems docker depends on docker itself to compile, and running `make build` from it downloads a docker container that only runs on x86 machines.

How can I run this on arm?

Comment: https://github.com/umiddelb/armhf/wiki/Installing,-running,-using-docker-on-armhf-(ARMv7)-devices

Comment: Saw that @BMW, yet, does not compile `docker` and that's what I'm trying

Comment: Have you checked [docker-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!searchin/docker-dev/Arm) on Google groups? There is some information.

Comment: AFAICS the section "Updating from Docker version 1.0.1" in the linked article is about _nothing but_ building Docker from source on an ARMv7 machine...